# Unity3D RayCast coming from world origin instead from specified random point?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to cast raycasts from random points inside my scene to sample positions to spawn enemies. But clearly the raycasts are coming from world 0,0,0 and actually passing by the random points.

Here's my code:

```
public Vector3 GetRandomPositionSpawnable (Vector3 origin, float radius)
{
     Vector3 randomPoint = origin + Random.insideUnitSphere * radius;

     if (Physics.Raycast(randomPoint, randomPoint + Vector3.down, out RaycastHit hit, Mathf.Infinity, LayerMask.GetMask("Scenery")))
     {
          //these are methods I made to draw permanent gizmos spheres and lines calling from anywhere
          Tools.DebugSphere(randomPoint, 10, Color.yellow); 
          Tools.DebugSphere(hit.point, 20, Color.red);
          Tools.DebugLine(randomPoint, hit.point, Color.white);

          return hit.point;
     }

     return Vector3.zero;
}
```

As you can see by these images, the red gizmos sphere aren't below the yellow ones, but actually are coming from world 0,0,0 and going to the randomly chosen point (and colliding after).

[a image with gizmosSpheres and gizmoLines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pl1b.png)

I was hoping tho get the nearest point below some randomly chosen points in space.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out. Raycasts directions are not a point world in space, they are a just the range between -1,-1,-1 and 1,1,1 you what it to point in relation the origin. Think like the direction is automatically added to the origin to make a vector3 world space point.